# What does the COM do on a DC/DC converter?

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, pinout

I got one of these DC/DC convert chips thats supposed to give a -25/25 V voltage output.

My "RGZ" model seems to be outputting -50/50 V and getting toasty.

I'm not sure what the COM is supposed to be connected to. I thought it was the "common" ground and should be connected to GND but my chip still ain't giving the correct voltage.

I got -VIN at (-5V), +VIN at +5V. What's COM and where do I connect it?

[image]
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/468/RJZ_RGZ-318051.pdf

Comment: RGZ is dual-output, so... yeah, it's the common return for the positive and negative supplies.

Comment: If you're supplying it with 10V instead of 5V (-5V to +5V == 10V) then that would explain the heat and unexpected behavior. Stop doing that or the smoke will leak out sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got -VIN at (-5V), +VIN at +5V.

[image]

*Figure 1. DC-DC converter wiring.*

Ensure that you have only 5 V between the input terminals. Your post makes it sound as though you have +/- 5 V (= 10 V) between the terminals and this would explain the heat.

> What's COM and where do I connect it?

COM is the common or mid-point on the output. Connect it to the GND or 0 V of your isolated circuit.

> My "RGZ" model seems to be outputting -50/50 V and getting toasty.

[image]

*Figure 2. The output voltage regulation.*

The open-circuit output voltage could be up to 25% higher than the nominal. If you are getting double then it is probably due to incorrect input voltage as explained above.

Decoupling capacitors:

Don't try omitting the decoupling capacitors. They will be required.

---

> Whats a good choice for the decoupling caps?

The datasheet doesn't say other than the maximum capacitive load table on page 1.

- I'd reckon that you stabilise the input with 100 - 470 µF in parallel with 100n.
- On the output I would aim for half the max capacitive load *including* any capacitors across the supply rails in the device you are powering.
- The 100 nF capacitors are better at handling high-frequency noise than the electrolytics are.

Comment: If you'll forgive me, whats a good choice for the decoupling caps? Not really sure how to choose them.

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have the RGZ-**05**15D, then is works like this. The output is isolated from the input.
But you could connect COM back to -Vin (0V) to have an easy +/-15V booster. But also to +Vin (5V) to have -10V +20V. Or any other combination, or not at all and use the isolation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2TStD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The device works on the principle of a [push-pull converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_converter). And is not regulated. You can make one easily for yourself with an [SN6501](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6501.pdf).